# can anyone suggest me, which Syntax of FindElement command can be used? Xpath / Full Xpath is not working for me in the LinkedIn bot

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, linkedin-api

**Xpath / Full Xpath is not allowing me to access Easy Apply in the LinkedIn bot.** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPFFu.png)

```
try:
    easy_apply = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="+Yx8O6UNSU67JGJE1z0tug=="]/div/ul[1]/li[2]/a')
    easy_apply.click()
    print("Easy Apply - successfully triggered")
    time.sleep(2)

except:
    print("Error Can't hold the Easy apply.")
```

Comment: that id is randomly generated each time the page is loaded

Comment: best to use full xpath or, use a div or other element which has a static class or static text.

Comment: Probably also avoid the [bare `except`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search for the "easy apply" button via text

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Create a WebDriver instance (e.g., Chrome)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Open a web page
driver.get("https://example.com")

try:
    # Find the button/anchor with case-insensitive text "Easy Apply"
    easy_apply = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'easy apply')]")

    # Click the button
    easy_apply.click()
    # Log Success
    print("Easy Apply - successfully triggered")
    time.sleep(2)

except:
    # Log Error
    print("Error Can't hold the Easy apply.")

# Close the WebDriver when done
driver.quit()
```

Comment: @SriBalajiPari if this solution solved your issue, could you mark it as the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
easy_apply = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Easy apply']")
easy_apply.click()
```